# Problem with modifying the state with spread syntax

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a react application and I have the following problem. I want to modify the state object in my reducer based on the parameters passed from action creator. To make it simplier I made an example in pure JS

State Object looks like this

```
const stateObj = {
  left: {
    data: [{ name: 'Adam', surname: "Test Adam" }]  
  },
  right: {
    data: [{ name: 'Tom', surname: 'Test Tom' }]  
  },
}
```

Data that is passed to reducer from an action creator looks like this

```
const id = 0; // In this case - I want to change the first item in array
const newValue = "Sample new value"; // new value for the property
const nameOrAge = 'name'; // which property to change
const leftOrRight = 'right'; // which part of the state I want to change
```

Based on the above parameters the result should be a copied state object with one property changed like below `name: 'Sample new value'`:

```
left: {
     data: [{ name: 'Adam', surname: "Test Adam" }]  
   },
   right: {
     data: [{ name: 'Sample new value', surname: 'Test Tom' }]  
   },
 }
```

What I have so far - kind of my reducer

```
const showModifiedData = (id, newValue, nameOrAge, leftOrRight) => {
  // I want to return the modified state here
  return {
    ...stateObj,
    [leftOrRight]: {
      ...stateObj[leftOrRight],
      data: // modify the name property based on the dynamic values from parameters
    }
   
  }
  
}
```

I'm struggling to properly change the `data` arry. ANy help apreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different approaches could be used.
One is to just copy the array, with slice or spread, and just assign the new object at the index.

For example

```
const showModifiedData = (id, newValue, nameOrAge, leftOrRight) => {
    const data = [...stateObj[leftOrRight].data];
    data[id] = {...data[id], [nameOrAge]: newValue};
    return {
        ...stateObj,
        [leftOrRight]: {
            ...stateObj[leftOrRight],
            data,
        }
    }

}
```

Note that using this approach you are only copying the object you are updating and the others are the same reference.

Comment: Isn't that mutating the state ? I want to avoid that

Comment: Nope, using the spread you copy the array, but not the objects inside it. Then you selectively assign a new object to the new array. So you are not mutating the original state.

Comment: I can't get it working with my reducer... could Your show me how to connect your solution with my reducer ?

Comment: Modified the answer, sorry for any error but I'm from mobile right now.

Answer (score 2):

Use `stateObj[leftOrRight].data.map()` to replace the property in each `data` object.

```js
const stateObj = {
  left: {
    data: [{ name: 'Adam', surname: "Test Adam" }]  
  },
  right: {
    data: [{ name: 'Tom', surname: 'Test Tom' }]  
  },
};

const id = 0; // In this case - I want to change the first item in array
const newValue = "Sample new value"; // new value for the property
const nameOrAge = 'name'; // which property to change
const leftOrRight = 'right'; // which part of the state I want to change

const showModifiedData = (id, newValue, nameOrAge, leftOrRight) => {
  return {
    ...stateObj,
    [leftOrRight]: {
      ...stateObj[leftOrRight],
      data: stateObj[leftOrRight].data.map((el, i) => i == id ? {...el, [nameOrAge]: newValue} : el)
    }
  }
}

console.log(showModifiedData(id, newValue, nameOrAge, leftOrRight));
```

Comment: Thanks for the super quick response !
I have one issue with Your solution. I want to modify only one object in `data` array - the one specified by  the `id` index variable. Your solution would change  every single object in the array. How can I deal with that ?

Comment: I added a conditional.

Comment: But I think this is getting more verbose than I really like with spread, and the other answer is a better way to do it.

Comment: <facepalm> it's so simple now when I see it ... Thank You very much sir !